# How do you download app from app store from C# app?

Tags: c#, app-store, itunes

I am looking for a way to downloa an app store app to my PC from a C# program.
I need it to be done automatically and without leaving the program's context.

I have 2 ideas 
1. using iTunes
2. implementing a component that uses the app store protocol for download

So...
How can I invoke iTunes and have download a specified app programaticaly?
Are there any documentation on App Store protocol?

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: And then you're going to run an iPhone app on your PC?